# Validação de campos nulos do JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

No meu sistema, tenho uma janela e um controller, mas por algum motivo, ele nunca esta lançando o erro, como esperado :

Método que faz a validação :

```
private void validacao(){
    if((form.txtNome.getText() != null) && (form.txtEnd.getText() != null) && (form.txtTel.getText() != null)){
        eventosForm();
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Todos os campos devem estar preenchidos !");
    }
}
```

Método que pega os valores dos campos :

```
private void eventosForm(){
    form.btnCadastrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
            cliente.setNome(form.txtNome.getText());
            cliente.setEndereco(form.txtEnd.getText());
            cliente.setTelefone(form.txtTel.getText());
            clienteDB.add(cliente);
            form.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Como disse antes, mesmo eu deixando todos os campos nulos, ele realiza o cadastro, acredito que possa ser por se tratar de um método void, mas não tenho certeza ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você inicia um `JTextField` sem passar nenhum valor de texto para ele(ex. `new JTextField()`), o campo é iniciado como vazio.

Logo, para verificar se este campo possui ou não algo digitado, você deve verificar se o retorno de `getText()` também está vazio.

Pense na lógica escrita do if:

```
Se:   
  (campo1 está nulo ou campo1 está vazio) ou (campo2 está nulo ou campo2 está vazio) 
então:
   exiba a mensagem;
senão:
   chame o método eventosForm()
```

Que seria em código:

```
 if ((form.txtNome.getText() == null || form.txtNome.getText().trim().isEmpty()) ||
  (form.txtEnd.getText() == null || form.txtEnd.getText().trim().isEmpty()) ||
  (form.txtTel.getText() == null || form.txtTel.getText().trim().isEmpty())) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Todos os campos devem estar preenchidos !");
 } else {
  eventosForm();
 }
```

Lembrando que deve-se sempre validar primeiro se um campo está nulo antes de checar se este mesmo campo está vazio, pois se em algum lugar do seu código um desses campos for configurado com valor `null`, ao validar novamente, vai estourar `NullPointerException` na hora de checar se está vazio.

Comment: Minha intensão é só chamar o método `eventosForm();` se **nenhum** campo estiver vazio e nulo, então a lógica não seria substituir todos `or` por `and` ?

Comment: @DanielSantos não, pois um campo pode está nulo **ou** vazio, são estados diferentes. Uma string está vazia quando seu tamanho é igual a 0, e nula quando não tem nenhum valor nela. Mas entre os pares de validações em cada campo, deve sim usar o `&&`.

Comment: Continua cadastrando, mesmo eu colocando o `&&` entre os pares de cada campo ...

Comment: @DanielSantos perdoe-me o equívoco, o código realmente estava com problemas na lógica booleana, havia feito sem testar antes. Agora está correta.

Comment: É necessário usar o trim() também, pois espaços em branco fazem com que o isEmpty() retorne false.

Comment: @hlucasfranca bem lembrado, valeu pelo aviso :)

Comment: @DanielSantos se a resposta lhe atendeu, seria interessante marcá-la como aceita, assim, servirá de referencia para outros usuarios :)

Answer (score 3):

Para facilitar a validação, caso sejam incluídos mais campos ou caso tenha que validar outras telas, você pode usar um método utilitário passando o `JTextField` desejado:

```
protected boolean estaVazio(JTextField campo) {
    return campo.getText() != null && !campo.getText().trim().isEmpty();
}
```

Chamando assim:

```
if ( estaVazio(form.txtNome.getText()) || estaVazio(form.txtEnd.getText()) 
    || estaVazio(form.txtTel.getText())) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Todos os campos devem estar preenchidos !");
} else {
    eventosForm();
}
```

O `trim()` é necessário, também, porque *ao chamar* `isEmpty()` *em um* `JTextField` *com espaços em branco, é retornado* **false**!